# Why is an aggregation with a group by so slow?

Tags: amazon-web-services, group-by, amazon-redshift, query-optimization

I have a table `[order]` in a Redshift instance with a row count of 780 000.
Running the following group by clause on the table takes 60+ seconds.
In MSSQL, exact same query takes 1 second.
Any advice on why Redshift takes so much longer and how to improve the query would be greatly appreciated.

```
select
    salesorderid
    ,max(orderid)           as max_order_id
    ,min(latestdelivery)    as min_latestdelivery
    ,max(latestdelivery)    as max_latestdelivery
    ,min(sourceid)          as min_sourceid
    ,max(sourceid)          as max_sourceid
    ,min(salesitem)         as min_salesitem
    ,max(salesitem)         as max_salesitem
    ,min(qty)               as min_qty
    ,max(qty)               as max_qty
    ,min(weight)            as min_weight
    ,max(weight)            as max_weight
    ,min(refb)              as min_refb
    ,max(refb)              as max_refb
    ,min(blocked)           as min_blocked
    ,max(blocked)           as max_blocked
    ,min(updatemode)        as min_updatemode
from public.order o
where o.datecreated >= getdate() - interval '24 month'
group by salesorderid;
```

explain:

```
XN HashAggregate  (cost=35513.57..52310.29 rows=419918 width=99)
->  XN Seq Scan on "order" o  (cost=0.00..9738.60 rows=606470 width=99)
Filter: (datecreated >= '2019-10-17 11:52:14'::timestamp without time zone)
```

Comment: How did you insert your data? With what command?

Comment: What is the SORTKEY on the table?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein +1 - also: what is the DISTKEY?

Comment: And are your `salesorderid`s unique?

Comment: I unfortunately did not insert the data so I cannot provide the insert command.
SORTKEY is on (salesorderid, datecreated).
DISTKEY is on (datecreated).
salesorderis's are not unique.

Answer (score 1):

While there are several things here that are not ideal there is likely that the cause for this to take 1 min is not in the SQL.  I'll itemize the issues I see later.

Your source table is less than 1M rows - very small by Redshift standards. Unlikely that the sort order or metadata staleness would cause a large issue.  The query is a simple aggregation and the explain plan shows that Redshift expects that this "should" take less than a second.  All of this leads me to focus on external confounding factors.

I'm going to assume that you measured the query time from the bench and not by system table data.  Let us know if this isn't the case.  If so you are looking at the full round trip through the database and not just execution time.  There are multiple steps that need to happen for the query to complete.  It needs to be compiled, scheduled through the WLM queues, executed, and results returned.  Any of these steps could be taking a long time, each for a number of reasons.

So the first step is to find how long the query is taking in each of these steps.  I like to start in the middle (queue and execute as this is often where things get slowed down but not always). STL_WLM_QUERY system table will show how long your query took through the queue as well as execution time.  One possibility is that your query got hung up waiting in queues and this would should you this.  It will also show the total execution time so you can see how long it took to run (this is all the EXPLAIN plan is focused on).  It is possible that something is off here but I'd keep reading.

If things went quickly through the queues and executed in reasonable time then we need to look as compile and return.  SVL_COMPILE will show how long it took for the query to compile but given the simplicity of this query it is highly unlikely that this is where your problem is.

A likely cause is in the return step.  EXPLAIN expects you to receive 419K rows of meaningful width - this possibly represents a sizable amount of data.  IF your networking between Redshift and yourself is of limited bandwidth this amount of data could take a good chunk of your run time to transmit.  STL_RETURN holds data from Redshift's perspective on this step.  You could also test this by rerunning your query with the results put into a temp table and see if that greatly improves the run time.  This is only my guess from afar.

The right way to go is to collect the data on where the time is being spent and act on that information.  Report back on this question if more guidance is needed at that point.

Now for some observations on the query itself.  I'd recommend that you NOT use a timestamp as the distribution key of your table.  You are unlikely to JOIN or GROUP BY a timestamp this will provide no help to executing your queries.  Since you are grouping by salesorderid that might be a good choice for distribution key.  Also you should use common WHERE clause columns as sort keys.  You have done this but made it the 2nd sort key after salesorderid.  This will likely steal all the power from datecreated and stop it from providing any benefit.  I'd suggest that you just have salesorderid as this sort key but this is base on looking at exactly 1 of your queries so take this as a poorly informed set of advice.  This all said it is unlikely that any of this will make much of a difference given the small size of the table.  There just isn't enough data here for these keys to create a large impact.